# What does the expression "comment faire pour (faire qch)" mean?

Tags: sens, expressions, questions

Can someone please explain to me what this expression means and how is it used. I see it a lot in French TED talks and I'm not sure of its meaning. For example at one point the presenter said:

> Vous souvenez-vous *comment moi j'ai fait pour* apprendre le mot « passementerie ».
>
> Mais même si... *comment peuvent-ils faire pour* apprendre leur sens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can translate "faire" by "manage".

> Vous souvenez-vous comment moi j'ai fait pour apprendre* le mot passementerie
>   Do you remember how did I manage to learn the word "passementerie" ?

It makes an emphasis on the manner you did it. It implies it is something not common, but you found a way to do it.

It is very common. You may often use it when someone solves a problem:

> Comment t'as fait pour finir aussi vite ?? (familiar)

« Comment [j'ai/t'as/il a/...] fait » is not formal, it is used on common language (a little familiar maybe, but not that much)

Comment: Oh I see  thanks a lot. Is it common in spoken French or it's rather formal?

Comment: It is very common, but it is not formal. I edit my answer.

Comment: *Manage* in English emphasizes the success, not the manner. You should drop this part. The explanation that follows is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Think about “Comment faire pour” this way: What are the actions it takes to obtain the desired result?

A sentence such as:

> Comment j'ai fait pour apprendre le mot « passementerie » ?

is about the actions you took. If you ask instead:

> Comment j'ai appris le mot « passementerie » ?

the question is much broader. Answering “from whom” or “where” you learned it would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute also "arriver à" for "faire pour": "....comment moi, je suis arrivé à apprendre le sens..." I came to learn the meaning... This construction may make it more obvious that a goal is being sought after and then achieved

Answer (score 0):

"Vous souvenez-vous comment moi j'ai fait pour apprendre* le mot passementerie"
translates:
"Do you remember how I managed to learn the word passementerie"

"mais même si... comment peuvent-t-il faire pour apprendre leur sense ?"
translates:
"Even if... how can they manage to learn their meaning?"

So yeah, "How to manage to" could be a quite accurate translation for "Comment faire pour"